# After installing a free theme, my wordpress turns into text mode when accessing remotely

Tags: themes

I just finished installing newest Wordpress on my local machine and then installed free theme `Hassiumize` from http://www.paddsolutions.com/. The problem is that the whole page is shown nicely when I access the page on that local machine. When I access from another machine, however, the page is displayed only in text mode.

Do you have any suggestions for this?

Comment: Sounds like your stylesheet isn't loading. What is the URL to **your** site?

Comment: I am not sure, but it loads fine in my local machine. Here is my demo installation on the free host: http://pho66.webege.com/w/

Comment: The stylesheet is loaded when I access that page. Looks like a browser problem (adblocker or something similar).

Comment: Your site loads its styles from http://pho66.webege.com/w/wp-content/themes/hassiumize/styles/style.php?c=1 However, I get an error when that file loads: `text/css (NS_ERROR_INVALID_CONTENT_ENCODING)` FireFox won't let me look at it at all but Chrome will load what it can. The last line it can load is `#featured-box .item img {` That is where the error is. Find where that rule is defined and you will make progress. Have you edited the stylesheets at all?

Comment: @s_ha_dum: no, I have not edit anything in stylesheets.

Comment: I just manually installed a fresh theme version in: pho66.webege.com/w2 , but the problem is still the same

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem loading the CSS-files. From what I'm guessing it is that your server doesn't support the compression of the file.

If I look at the loaded styles that is included on your site it ends unexpectedly in the middle of it. The URL it is loaded from is: `http://pho66.webege.com/w/wp-content/themes/hassiumize/styles/style.php?c=1`

When I change the URL to not include the `?c=1` it loads the complete file.

I downloaded the theme and looked in the "style.php" file, and what the `?c=1` does is adding compression with gzip:

```
$compress = (isset($_GET['c']) && $_GET['c']);
$force_gzip = ($compress && 'gzip' == $_GET['c']);
```

Try editing your main CSS file to not include the query string, that might solve the problem. In your **style.css** change `@import 'styles/style.php?c=1';` to `@import 'styles/style.php';`

Comment: sorry for late response. I just tried to edit the file, but the problem is not gone. when accessing on the machine, the whole page was loaded fine, but when accessing from other machine, it still displayed the text only